# How to utilize the High Performance cores on Apple Silicon

Tags: multithreading, macos, performance, apple-m1

I have developed a macOS app which is heavily relying on multithreading (a call center simulator). It runs fine on my iMac 2019 and fills up all cores nicely. In my test scenario it simulates app. 1.4 mio. telephone calls in total in 100 iterations, each iteration as a dispatch item on a parallel dispatch queue.

[image: Core usage on Intel iMac]

Now I have bought a new Mac mini with M1 Apple Silicon and I was eager to see how the performance develops on that test machine. Well, it’s not bad but not as good as I expected:

| System | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| iMac 2019, Intel 6-core i5, 3.0 GHz, Catalina macOS 10.15.7 | 19.95 s |
| Mac mini, M1 8-core, Big Sur macOS 11.2, Rosetta2 | 26.85 s |
| Mac mini, M1 8-core, Big Sur macOS 11.2, native ARM | 17.07 s |

Investigating a little bit further I noticed that at the start of the simulation all 8 cores of the M1 Mac are filled up properly but after a few seconds only the 4 high efficiency cores are used any more.

[image: Core usage on M1 Mac mini]

I have read the Apple docs „Optimize for Apple Silicon with performance and efficiency cores“ and double checked that the dispatch queue for the iterations is set up properly:

```
let simQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
```

But no success. After a few seconds of running the high performance cores are obviously not utilized any more. I even tried to set up the queue with qos set to `.userInteracive` up that didn’t help either. I also flagged the dispatch items with proper qos but that didn’t change anything. It looks to me that other apps (e.g. XCode) do utilize the high performance cores even for a longer time.

Does anybody know how to force a M1 Mac to utilize the high performance cores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"M1 8 core" is really "M1 4 performance + 4 power saving cores". I expect it to have be a bit more performance than an Intel 6 core, but not much. Exactly has you see, 15% faster than six Intel cores or about as fast as 7 Intel cores would be. The current M1 chips are *low end* processors. "A bit better than Intel six cores" is quite good.

Your code *must* be running on the performance cores, otherwise there would be no chance at all to come close to the Intel performance. In that graph, nothing tells you which cores are used.

What happens most likely is that all cores start running, each trying to do one eighth of the work, and after about 8 seconds the performance cores have their work done. Then the power saving cores move their work to the performance cores. And you are just misinterpreting the image as only low performance cores doing the work.

Comment: OK, I'm convinced. My app is running on the performance cores. I checked it with Instruments. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the activity monitor graph (type Cmd+2 upon opening activity monitor) it will show whether the core you hover is Eff or Perf. Also, Cmd+3 will show charts with labels, even clearer.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that Apple has put a preference on using efficiency cores over performance for many reasons. Battery life being one, and most likely thermal reasons as well. This is the big question mark with a SoC that originally was designed for smartphones and tablets. MacOS is a much heavier OS then IOS or iPad OS. Apple most likely felt that performance cores were only needed in the cases where maximum throughput was needed. No doubt, I think some including myself with a M1 Mac Mini would like a way to adjust this balance between efficiency and performance cores. Personally overall, I would prefer all cores be capable of switching between efficiency and performance such as in Intel's Speed shift technology. This may come along with the M1's advancements in terms of Mac Pro models and other Pro models.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: its not the heat, i made a setup with active cooling on my m2 mac, temperatures literally wont go over 50c and it will still do this... this is deliberate way to make your powerful device less powerful so you go buy the more expensive thing... your apple m2 air is crazy powerful beast but it deliberately overuses efficiency cores because ... planet